# Device Token Phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

Hello I am using ionic to write a hybrid app that will send push notifications. I have a question to setup the phonegap-plugin-push.

I am trying to get my device token and send it to my nodejs server.

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Here is my current code:

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $window, $http) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       
  });
})
```

How can I get and store my device token using this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md) example from phone-gap documents you should call this function on your device ready (also safer to use a 1 second delay for this function).

code :

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
android: {
    senderID: "12345679"
},
browser: {
    pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
},
ios: {
    alert: "true",
    badge: "true",
    sound: "true"
},
windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});
```

After that  you should post the `data.registrationId` to server to keep it for sending notifications .